# "Django-filter" Is it possible to use FilterClass(FilterSet) MultipleChoiceFilter within ViewSet methods? Django 1.11, Python 2.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-1.11

I have my class `ClassFilter(FilterSet)` with some of the Filters fx. `MultipleChoiceFilter`, `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` etc. in it:

```
class ClassFilter(FilterSet):
    something_severity = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Something.SEVERITY_CHOICES, method='something_severity_filter', widget=CSVWidget)

def something_severity_filter(self, queryset, name, severities):
    if severities:
        queryset = queryset.filter(something_state=Something.STATE_SOMETHING)
        ...
    return queryset

class Meta:
    model = Something
    fields = []
```

It works perfect when it comes to filtering endpoints. It is assigned to the class like:

```
class ClassViewSet(mixins....., DefaultApiViewSet):
    filter_class = ClassFilter
```

by having `filter_class = ClassFilter`. Everything works just fine but now I am in in doubts if I may use the `ClassFilter` `MultipleChoiceFilter` within `ClassViewSet` methods.

This means by executing `POST` method in `ClassViewSet`, I want to get the `MultipleChoiceFilter` from `FilterClass` to filter on my method by getting it as `SomethingFilter.get_filters()` method

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def something_update(self, req):
...
all_filters = SomethingFilter.get_filters()

for serializer_filter in serializer_filters:
    for filter in all_filters:
        if(serializer_filter == filter):
            f = all_filters[filter]
```

Now the `f` is a filter which I require so that is `MultipleChoiceFilter`. **But** when I try to filter with that filter it throws an error.

```
f.filter(queryset, [('LOW')]) #filter the queryset with the filter based on LOW choice
```

Throws:

```
assertionError: Filter 'something_severity' must have a parent FilterSet to find '.something_severity_filter()'
```

In **documentation** for `django-filter` it is exactly line: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/f4866a9852d569861651cc733f909fe0e378131b/django_filters/filters.py#L823

So my point is **if there is** a way to actually filter a method like this with a `ClassFilter` like I have. If there is some other way how to actually do it correctly. I bet there is so I will not eventually have to do other filtering and keep the low-coupling.

If there is something that is not clearly said let me add towards this question! Thank you very much for every help.

Comment: You are aware that 2.7 has been unsupported for more than two years, yes? That it is comparable to Windows 7 in terms of how outdated it is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What exactly is your point? The tag specifying the version of python seems correct? 
Also it looks like that the package supports both python 2.7 and 3+ so the code that does the filtering, which i think is what OP is asking about, should be pretty much the same?

Comment: The point is that there is no good reason to be using it, and it is not receiving security updates, which seems especially important for a web app.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder that they should update their entire codebase and the hundreds of dependencies. It's not that I don't agree, but it's pretty off topic. The code he is asking about is very likely related to a specific version of the django-filter package, and not a specific version of python.

Comment: It would be nice if I could get answer to the actual question or if anyone else encountered such a problem and have a solution. Anyways thanks for the fast answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have come back to the problem and come up with a solution.

When you have setup some filters that you need in FilterSet class(MultipleChoiceFilter,...)

```
class CarFilter(FilterSet):
    wheel = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Wheel.CHOICES, method='wheel_filter', widget=CSVWidget)

    def wheel_filter(self, queryset, name, cars):
        if cars:
            ...
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = []
```

You have to **implement** filter class in the ViewSet:

```
class CarViewSet(DefaultApiViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_class = CarFilter
```

You may **use** filter of your liking in the ViewSet methods when you set it like this:

**IMPORTANT! -** When using `widget=CSVWidget` in MultipleChoiceFilter above, it works like that:

```
def car_method(self, req):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    self.filter_class({"wheel": "MEDIUM,LOW"}, queryset).qs
```

When we are **NOT** using `widget=CSVWidget` it works like that:

```
def car_method(self, req):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    self.filter_class({'alert_severity': ['MEDIUM', 'LOW'], 'update_state': ['is_updated']}}, queryset).qs
```

Finished! We filtered cars based on their wheels.